# Android RotateAnimation not working as expected

Tags: java, android, animation, android-animation

I want to animate an imageView in this way: (sign of angles defined as in trigonometry)

1. smooth rotation from 0 to -45
2. smooth rotation from -45 to +45
3. smooth rotation from +45 to -45
4. restart to 2 (infinite loop)

With the code below, I get:

1. smooth rotation from 0 to +45
2. immediate comme back to 0
3. smooth rotation from 0 to -45
4. smooth rotation from -45 to 0
5. restart to 3 (infinite loop)

So, not at all what I want !

Anybody sees how to solve this issue?

Thanks !

Here is my code:

```
float angle = 45f;

        RotateAnimation rotateAnimation1 = new RotateAnimation(0, -angle,
                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);            
        rotateAnimation1.setStartOffset(0);
        rotateAnimation1.setDuration(2000);
        rotateAnimation1.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());



        RotateAnimation rotateAnimation2 = new RotateAnimation(-angle, angle,
                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
        //  animationSet.addAnimation(rotateAnimation);
        rotateAnimation2.setStartOffset(0);
        rotateAnimation2.setDuration(4000);
        rotateAnimation2.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());



        RotateAnimation rotateAnimation3 = new RotateAnimation(angle, -angle,
                Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);       
        rotateAnimation3.setStartOffset(4000);
        rotateAnimation3.setDuration(4000);
        rotateAnimation3.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());



        final AnimationSet animSet1 = new AnimationSet(true);
        animSet1.setFillEnabled(true);
        animSet1.addAnimation(rotateAnimation1);


        final AnimationSet animSet2 = new AnimationSet(true);
       // animSet2.setFillEnabled(true);
        animSet2.addAnimation(rotateAnimation2);
        animSet2.addAnimation(rotateAnimation3);


        animSet1.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

                view.startAnimation(animSet2);


            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
            }
        });


        animSet2.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {

                view.startAnimation(animSet2);

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
            }
        });





        view.startAnimation(animSet1);
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason your view returns to zero is that the rotation property of the view is not changed. You should set the rotation to the view on after the first animation ends or use `ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(imageview ,"rotation", 0f, 360f);` which by default sets the view's rotation.

Comment: I am not sure to understand your answer. May you copy/paste the full corrected code in your answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**1. smooth rotation from 0 to -45:** Invert angle sign and `setFillAfter(true)` so view keeps ended animation position

```
    RotateAnimation rotateAnimation1 = new RotateAnimation(0, 45f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f); 
    rotateAnimation1.setFillAfter(true); //This keeps view at animation ended position            
    rotateAnimation1.setStartOffset(0);
    rotateAnimation1.setDuration(2000);
    rotateAnimation1.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
```

**2. smooth rotation from -45 to +45:** Set animation start angle to 0, because view it is already rotated.

```
    // Since view already is at -45 position due to rotateAnimation1.setFillAfter(true), now start point is 0 again
    RotateAnimation rotateAnimation2 = new RotateAnimation(0, -90,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
    rotateAnimation2.setFillAfter(true);
    rotateAnimation2.setStartOffset(0);
    rotateAnimation2.setDuration(4000);
    rotateAnimation2.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
```

The rest of the steps are straightforward following the logic above.